# How to loop a Google script so values are placed below previous data set?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that scrapes information and returns the cleaned data. However, I can't get the loop to work so that once the first data set is pulled, the next data set is pasted below the first data set. The goal is to run the script and have it pull info on all of the URLs in Column A under "Data Input" and have it paste all of the cleaned data in the "Final List" tab.

```
function DataCleaner() {

//Paste next set - THIS SECTION ISN'T WORKING
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var source = ss.getRange('Almost!A:M');
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Final List'), true);
  ss.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activateAsCurrentCell();
  ss.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activateAsCurrentCell();
  source.copyTo(ss.getCurrentCell(), {contentsOnly: true});

  //Sort filtered results
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getRange('A1').activate();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Final List'), true);
  ss.getActiveSheet().sort(2, false);
};
```

Fixed Script:

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Almost'); 
var source=sh.getRange('Almost!A:M'); 
var dest=ss.getSheetByName('Final List') 
source.copyTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1), {contentsOnly: true});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function runOne() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Almost');
  var source=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn());
  var dest=ss.getSheetByName('Final List')
  source.copyTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

Comment: I had to change it a little but that worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Almost');
  var source=sh.getRange('Almost!A:M');
  var dest=ss.getSheetByName('Final List')
  source.copyTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1), {contentsOnly: true});

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.getCurrentCell()` (which depends on where the cursor is currently), you might consider [`.getLastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow), which returns the numerical index of the last row that contains data.  Increment this by one to get the row where you want to start pasting.